# Write JSON data in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want a json output as follows:

```
{
    "id": "c200",
    "name": "Aneesh",
    "email": "an@gmail.com",
    "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            },
    "phone": {
                "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                "home": "00 000000",
                "office": "00 000000"
            }
}
```

how to write a PHP code using json_encode for this output? Thanks! Cheers!

Comment: you can't have 2 `phone` keys, alternatively, you can add another dimension inside `phone`, then you can have them both

Comment: Its just an example, my actual data is something different and a bit complex. If you'll could answer this, it might just be helpful with the actual data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have said in the comments, that won't be possible because they share the same key.

Alternatively, you could create another dimension inside `phone`. Example:

```
$values = array(
    'id' => 'c200',
    'name' => 'Aneesh',
    'email' => 'an@gmail.com',
    'phone' => array(
        array(
            "mobile" => "+91 0000000000",
            "home" => "00 000000",
            "office" => "00 000000",
        ),
        array(
            "mobile" => "+91 0000000000",
            "home" => "00 000000",
            "office" => "00 000000",
        ),
    ),
);

echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode($values, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Should output this:

```
{
    "id": "c200",
    "name": "Aneesh",
    "email": "an@gmail.com",
    "phone": [
        {
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "office": "00 000000"
        },
        {
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "office": "00 000000"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jut create an array and pass it to the json_decode, like this:

```
$arr = array("id"=> "c200", "name"=> "Aneesh", "email"=> "an@gmail.com",
"phone"=>array("mobile"=> "+91 0000000000", "home" =>"00 000000", "office"
=>"00 000000"));

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get JSON output with PHP, is to simply make a PHP array, and then `echo json_encode($array);`.

To explain, for your code:

```
$array = array(  "id"=>"c200",
                 "name"=>"Aneesh",
                 "email"=> "an@gmail.com",
                 "phone"=> array(array(  "mobile"=>"+91 0000000000",
                                         "home"=> "00 000000",
                                         "office"=>"00 000000"),
                                 array(  "mobile"=>"+91 0000000000",
                                         "home"=> "00 000000",
                                         "office"=>"00 000000"
)));

echo json_encode($array);
```

The nice thing about json_encode is it will take care of special characters that need to be escaped in JSON for you, so you can put whatever you want in the array.

Answer (score -1):

You can get an idea from this:

```
var arr ={};
arr['name'] = "random";
arr['contact']= {};
arr['contact']['first']="3333333";
arr['contact']['second']="2222222";

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: console.log is used for debugging , for your information

Comment: Please do not use 'var' keyword, it has been depreciated in PHP 5.x

Comment: @rahulmr he using PHP not JS/jQuery